# Wordpress: /0 added to URL when no specific AJAX call exists

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am seeing Wordpress landing pages in Google GA4 that have /0 (or /0/0) added to the URL, which generally means an AJAX call with no `die()` at the end of the function.

I have no calls for these pages in my code. I do have calls for other Post types but these functions have `wp_die()` in the function.

What is the mechanism that is making these calls? Most have engagement times < 1 sec so are bots or crawlers but, presumably, the response is 200 to trigger a GA4 event.

Comment: AJAX itself usually does not use `die()`, as this is a PHP function, not a JS function. Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any. As I say, I am seeing these URLs in GA but there is nothing I can see on the website that creates calls to those URLs. The `wp_die()` function is contained in the Wordpress AJAX functions file.